# How to structure this Fragment / RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I know this is somewhat of a design question but I do have specific questions for it. I'm trying to understand how to handle a situation like this one:

Let's say I have a RecyclerViewFragment which loads a RecyclerView containing a bunch of Toy objects.

In one situation: Maybe this RecyclerViewFragment is part of a ViewPager on main display. There is a FloatingActionButton add-button present over this RecyclerView. You click the + button and you can add a new Toy to the list. Or you can click a Toy from the list directly and a floating menu pops up with Edit/Delete buttons, and pressing Edit lets you edit the Toy's details in a DialogFragment, or clicking Delete removes it from the RecyclerView.

In another situation: Now I am in a separate part of the app where I want to choose toys to use. So I press a button and a DialogFragment appears with a RecyclerView of Toys. I can click a Toy and it'll be added to my cart.

**It seems like I should be re-using the same RecyclerView code in both situations**, since they both involve a list of the same Toys. The only difference is that in one situation, I can add Toys and edit Toy details, and in the other situation, there is no Add button and clicking on a toy does something different (adding to a cart as opposed to bringing up an Edit/Delete dialog).

Is this the correct way to handle this:

1. Communication from Fragment to Activity: Interfaces? Have the RecyclerViewFragment, in the onAttach method, assign a listener of my design to the context. Then when a row of the RecyclerView is pressed, the callback is triggered. Now the underlying Activity can decide what to do with that press -- show the Edit/Delete dialog in one situation, add the Toy to a Cart in the other situation. Either way, the click item sends the Toy to the calling Activity so it can decide what to do with it.
2. Communication from Activity to Fragment: Now what about the situation with the Add button? This Add button would not be intrinsically part of the RecyclerViewFragment, so when I click Add, it would bring up the details dialog box where I can give the Toy details, and then press OK to add it. So somehow I have to transfer this new Toy to the Fragment to have it added to the RecyclerView. Would I simply do something like this:

   ```
   RecyclerViewFragment recyclerViewFragment = (RecyclerViewFragment ) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TOY_RECYCLERVIEW");
   recyclerViewFragment.getNewToyAndRefreshList(newToy);
   ```

and then in the RecyclerViewFragment:

```
public void getNewToyAndRefreshList(Toy newToy) {
    toyList.add(newToy);
    Collections.sort(toyList); //Toy has Comparable implemented, sort by name
    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Am I on the right track? Is there a different way to fix this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's certainly a design question, but IMHO there's a very specific issue on it and I believe it's a good question (reason I'm answering), but that also means other developers might have other approaches to solve the issue.

**1.** that is a totally fair and acceptable approach to it. You let the fragment be simple UI element and let someone else (the activity) implement the click behavior.

For this approach remember to code it only against the interface. That means, don't cast it to your activity. For example:

```
// do this
toyClickListener.onToyClicked(toy);

// don't do this
((MyActivity)getActivity()).onToyClicked(toy);
```

That way you keep the "simple UI element" be completely unaware of who is implementing the behavior.

**2.** IMO for this kind of scenario (specially on RecyclerView.Adapter) the best thing to do is to forget the UI and only focus on the data. And how speciafically you implement this, will vary on what is your data source.

But the base idea is that you have somewhere a data repo (DB?) and anyone using data from there, should subscribe to changes to it.

So you override `RecyclerView.Adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver` and `unregisterAdapterDataObserver` add the subscription/listener code, something like that:

```
@Override registerAdapterDataObserver(RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver observer) {
   super.registerAdapterDataObserver(observer);
   db.subscribe(this, toyList);
}

@Override unregisterAdapterDataObserver(RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver observer) {
   db.unsubscribe(this);
   super.unregisterAdapterDataObserver(observer);
}

@Override public void onDbDataUpdate(new Data comes here){
    update the data, and call .notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

that way once the `FAB +` and then dialog is clicked the new Toy gets added to the DB and the adapter gets "automatically" notified.

So if this data comes from a SQLite you can call on the cursor [`registerContentObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#registerContentObserver(android.database.ContentObserver)) if it's a RealmDB you'll use [`addChangeListener`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#auto-updating-results), even Android databinding libraries have a [`ObservableList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableList.html)

Comment: Regarding point 1, yes, I should have clarified but I did indeed mean to do `toyClickListener.onToyClicked(toy);` since this does not make any assumption about what was `toyClickListener` is assigned to.

Comment: Regarding point 2, a question: you say `that way once the FAB + and then dialog is clicked the new Toy gets added to the DB and the adapter gets "automatically" notified.` Right now in my app what I am doing is: Adding the Toy to the list and sorting it, while ALSO adding the Toy to the database. Is this preferable to the other method of just updating the database and then reloading the entire list from the db? In other words comparing the cost of sorting list + inserting into db, vs. inserting into db + reloading entire list from db? Either way I call notify on the adapter.

Comment: As I said on the answer. Do everything based on the data. That way the UI elements don't need to know about each other. Use `registerAdapterDataObserver` and `unregisterAdapterDataObserver` on the adapter to subscribe/unsusbscribe from the DB. That way the UI elements are independent of each other and you can change them anyway you want that the adapter will keep in sync wth the data.

Comment: I am a little confused how this registering observer thing works and if it's something I can easily use in my app. Right now my adapter takes in a list of Toy objects and then creates a ViewHolder, and I do things like assign row XMLs with names pulled from toy.getName(). When getting from or saving to the db, I call functions in a DatabaseHelper that I've written myself which handles all the SQL selects/inserts. Does this new approach you suggest operate completely differently?

Comment: I see you marked as `correct`, but to answer this last comment. You have to somehow keep "contact" with the DB. The `Cursor` have a `registerContentObserver` method. I guess you could, instead of using `registerAdapterDataObserver`, keep the cursor open on the Fragment, onStart/onStop you register it and onDestroyView you close the cursor. When the fragment receives the `onChange` from the DB, it calls `notify` on the adapter.